# What should I consider when converting a double-basin sink to a single-basin?

Tags: plumbing, sink

I'm not a handyman. But I want to save money.
I've never worked with any plumbing (or electrical work (or pretty much any other diy work other than in the yard)).

We're remodeling our kitchen a little. We've placed an order for new counter-tops, but Lowe's has said that we have to handle the sink installation ourselves (or hire an outside contractor I guess). I'd like to do it myself, but this seems like a large project for a first-timer.

The current setup is a drop-in, double-basin sink with a disposal. We would like to install a single-basin, undermount sink, and convert the plumbing/disposal to accommodate this.

Could someone tell me what to expect here? First thing, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to handle installation if I can't install an undermount until they arrive with the counters to begin with. Beyond that though, how hard of a plumbing project is this?

[image]

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Didn't the counter guys ask for the sink so they could measure it and make a cut out for it at the factory? Or did you just order some stone slabs from Lowe's? (who did the measuring?) I'm not sure how much money that's going to save you if you don't own the tools and can't work stone. I'm assuming it's stone because AFAIK, you can't under-mount to anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove everything currently under the sink that is not glued and use a rags to plug the drain pipes.  Next, let the counter guys do there work and install the sink.  There is nothing to do until they are done.

After they are done, follow the install instructions on the disposal.  After that is done, mount a new p-trap kit from one of the drain pipes to the disposal outlet.  Choose which one works best.  The other drain pipe you will need to cap.  Since this is under a sink, you can use a compression based cap so if in the future you decide to go back to a two sink setup it will be an easy job to removing the cap.

There is no harm in trying and if you find it doesn't work/leak just call a plumber.  The plumber I use, this would just be a service call charge ($45) to install.

Also if you plan to reuse your current disposal, remove it and the mounting ring before the counter guys come.  I had a friend who had they counter/sink redone and the counter guys left with the disposal mounting ring still attached to the old sink.  They had to buy new hardware to mount their old disposal.

Comment: +1 for the counter guys doing the sink. A drop-in on a plastic/wood counter top is DIY, no problem. But an under-mount on stone is much more difficult and beyond DIY, unless that's what you do for a living.

Comment: @Mazura I was just assuming the under-mount would be installed by the counter guys.  ctote, make sure the sink is in the counter guys scope of work.  Most home owners do not have the tools to mount the sink.